# Laravel/Vue - Pass URL to Component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, routes

I'd like to pass a `route('name', $id)` to a vue component. In this case, this would be quite easy, since its only one URL with the parameter.

But what do I have to do if I'd like to pass in an array of URLs? How to tell PHP/Laravel to make an array, where the URL is present without the `$id` part.

For example:

```
<custom-name
        data="{!! $urlData!!}"
        id="{!! $id !!}">
</custom-name>
```

And `$urlData` consists of `['url1'=> 'test/{id}/abc', 'url2'=> 'test/{id}/xyz']`.
The Plan is that I can build a vue component where I loop through the URLs and build a table with links to those URLs in it. I need the possibility to mutate these URLs before they are put into the table. But I need it to be done in the component.

So the question is: if it is possible in laravel to get the (i would call it) raw URL data like it is present in `Route::getRoutes()` but only for routes, I need no all. To be more precise, the problem is that the `route()` function need the corresponding `$id` Value in order to return an URL. But i need the URI like `test/{id}/xyz`. So i can generate the URLs in the component. I try to do it the Laravel-Way-Of-Life and I really like not to hard code it.

Hopefully, someone could lend me some help. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you, you have a bunch of routes and you need their URLs, right? If that is the case you can access it with some helpers methods built in laravel, and i can see that you want it with query strings etc.

You can use access them via the request with the `fullUrl()` helper, or just the `path()` helper if you dont need the query string.
Further reading on this is here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests

Comment: Not exactly. I have a number of datasets with different ids. And every url i need to set up is followed by the id. Since i really like to use the laravel way of life and not hardcoding the url i really want to use the `route('name')` function. Ideally i can give the uri which is generated by the route() function to my vue component. But the problem is that the function need the id value in order to give the URL.